# Reporting Services Prompt Area Functionality

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters, prompt

I have a user control which is driven by data from a sql database. Each user control contains a query, which can be altered at runtime with parameters. I would like to replicate the functionality of the reporting services viewer, which has the prompt area as seen in the image below.

[image: Prompt Area]

The example shown is made up of a single label and textbox. I am currently working towards an implementation like this. However it would be beneficial to be able to provide the users with a list of valid values, to ensure valid data is returned. It would also be nice to have dependencies between controls.

Does anyone know of an examples/implementations of something similar to this? Or any resources which could help with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference for others. I managed to implement this functionality using a list of a custom class along with a items collection.

Shown below is the Xaml. You can see the ItemsSource is bound to a list of my parameter class, and the item template binds a label/textbox to properties for each parameter.

```
<Grid Background="Silver">
    <ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Parameters}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Labels" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Prompt}" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="200" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
```

This is the output, for now it is as simple as labels and textboxes. I will come back to this and improve to use combos with limited values.

[image: Prompt View]